# Assign Javascript Variable Value to HTML href and function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables

could anybody suggest how I can put the javascript variable into the html href tag and code. Specifically, when loading the page, I want the following code can define div id and pass as the argument in its javascript function toggle 5 with the values of count_newsCat. For example, the first div would have id 'newsCat1', the second one 'newsCat2', etc..

The code is as below:

```
   <script>count_newsCat = 1;</script>
    {% for tag_field in tag_table %}
    <div name="{{tag_field.tag_name}}" class="tile" id="newsCat_gp" >
      <span onclick="this.parentNode.style.display = 'none';" class="closebtn">&times;</span>
      <a id="imageDivLink" href="javascript:toggle5('newsCat' + count_newsCat, 'list_div', 'imageDivLink');"><img src=  "{% static '/img/minus.png' %}"></a>
      <div class="tile__name"><b><font size="2px">{{tag_field.tag_name}}</b></font></div>
      <div class="tile__list" id="newsCat" + <script>count_newsCat;</script> style="display: block;"></div>                   
    </div>  
    <script>count_newsCat++;</script>
    {% endfor %}
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Not surprisingly, native dom and browser doesn't support this. You can only achieve this with some templating system(underscore templates for example) that compiles to static html files.

Answer (score 1):

if you use ES5 you could use templates like this:

```
`<a href='javascript:toggle5("${DivID}","list_div","imageLink")'>Link</a>`
```

if not, you could do the same with any template library like handlebar, so It will be like this:

```
for(var x = 10; x > 0; x--){
  var html = handlebar(source, {id:x,div:"list_div",link:"imageLink"})
  return template(html)
}// I dont remember pretty well the syntax of handlebars, find it in google
```

and your template will be something like this

```
<a href='javascript:toggle5("{{DivID}}","{{list_div}}","{{imageLink}}")'>Link</a>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution, I just figure out that I can achieve the same purpose in the Django template by using {{ forloop.counter }} which will do what count_newsCat++ does.

Comment: Glad to help, happy coding!